# http response code is OK when it should not be

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest

I have a restful web service. If someone calls a particular method with the wrong key, I return this:

```
OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
response.StatusDescription = "Invalid key provided.";
```

If I call it using Firefox with Firebug running, send an invalid key and handle the error in my calling code like:

```
string serviceResponse = "";
try
{
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
    string statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
    string statusDescription = response.StatusDescription.ToString();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    serviceResponse = ex.Message;
}
```

- the Response headers show:

HTTP:1.1 200 OK

Having handled the error, I can show a message on the screen. However, as soon as the 'using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)' line is hit, an error is thrown and the response object seems to be discarded.

If I don't put the HttpWebResponse code in a try catch block, a 401 unauthorized message shows in the browser but Firebug now shows:

HTTP:1.2 500 Internal Server Error

... which is weird, as I am sending a 401 back.

What is the point, in a Restful web service, of setting the response StatusCode and StatusDescription as, in a browser calling the web service, as soon as a 401 or 500 StatusCode is encountered, an error is thrown and the Response object discarded.

If a 500 or 401 is returned, how are you supposed to read the StatusDescription?